# Looking for a way to make a distributed drive using wasted hard disk spaces

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

In our LAN we have around 10 Windows 8 computers with 2TB hard disks each, and since 99% of the files we work with are located in Samba drives on a Linux server that we have, there is a lot of wasted hard disk space sitting around in our LAN (around 20TB).

I was wondering if there is a way or a tool or something that I could use to make a shared, distributed file system that we could use the wasted disk space.

I have worked with Gluster FS, under linux before, I'm wondering if there is something similar to that for Windows or not.

Answer (score 2):

How about [tahoe-lafs](http://www.tahoe-lafs.org)? From the FAQ:

> Q6: Does Tahoe-LAFS work on Windows?
>
> A: Yes. ...

If I recall correctly, you can access it via ftp, sftp, and some sort of a client.
A good sftp windows client would be [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Comment: Tahoe-LAFS can be complex to set up but works very nicely.  You can access via its web interface, its command line interface, or its SFTP frontend, which works with WinSCP.  The neat thing about Tahoe is that you can specify redundancy parameters so you can make it where if some of your nodes aren't available, you can get the whole file.  The security model of it is pretty nice too.